# How to use the same variable on other classes or files

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a newbie in Flutter. How can i use the same variable on other classes or files? Let's say i have a **bool _checkbox = false;** how can i use it on other files?

Comment: I don't think it's clear your question. Ex Rewrite in more detail, please.

Comment: your question is not clear enough, do you want to reuse a widget or a variable? It will be nice if you illustrate a scenario

Comment: Do you mean you want to reuse the variable `_checkbox' in another class ?

Comment: Yes sorry i meant a variable , @Madhan

Comment: sorry i meant a variable , @xahid_rocks

Comment: In dart underscore means private member. Remove the underscore `_` , then by creating an instance of the class you can access the member variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a variable all over the app, you can declare a class like this

```
class GlobalVer {
  static bool get checkedBox => false;
}
```

suppose,this is in `class.dart` file.To use the contents of it, you need to import the file, and use it.see below ...

first import it, `import 'package:test_app/class.dart';` ,then

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SecondPage"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                );
              },
              child: Text(GlobalVer.checkedBox.toString()))),
    );
  }
}
```

use it in other pages too! after import the class,

```
class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ThirdPage"),
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text(GlobalVer.checkedBox.toString())));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have **foo.dart** as

```
bool _checkBoxValue = false;
String _string = "A string variable";
```

then you can use those global variables inside of the **other.dart** file by importing this file into the **other.dart** file. for example,

```
import './other.dart';

int stringVariableLength = _string.length;
```